# How to map unicode characters to math symbols?

Tags: math-mode, unicode, unicode-math

I have documentation with some mathematics, that I want to convert via LaTeX, but I'd also like to keep it as much readable in source as possible (as it's more for me than anybody else). Since I can write many mathematical symbols directly with digraphs in vim and they show correctly in fonts I use, I would like to use them instead of the TeX commands. There is a package `unicode-math` that is supposed to do it, but it would need lualatex and does not work anyway [(bug report)](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2163/).

Now I am really using just a handful of symbols. Is it possible, and if it is, how, to map the characters I want to use manually? I have looked at the `inputenc` documentation, but couldn't make much sense of it and didn't notice relevant examples. Or, alternatively, can I workaround [the bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2163/) somehow?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This seems a job for the `newunicodechar` package. Can you give a short example showing the "handful of symbols" you need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting around the bug is easy: Add `\setmathfont{lmodern-math.otf}` after loading `unicode-math`. Btw: `unicode-math` can also be used with xelatex.

And if you want to declare definitions for utf8-input you can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{222B}{\int}%U+222B= integral
\begin{document}
$∫f(x)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried both. Both worked, but `lualatex` didn't like some other things about the doxygen output, so I chose the later.

Answer (score 10):

With the `newunicodechar` package you don't even need to hunt through tables of Unicode characters (this assumes `pdflatex` is used):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{bm}

\newunicodechar{ɑ}{\alpha}
\newunicodechar{β}{\beta}
\newunicodechar{}{\bm{\alpha}}

\begin{document}
$ɑ +  = β$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I eventually used the raw `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` as I see the codepoints in Vim anyway.