# Use symbols instead of text for commands

Tags: equations, symbols, syntax

Whenever I type a longer equation it gets unreadable very quickly.
Is it possible to shorten the expression

```
\alpha(z,n)=\left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi i}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k+n}{x^{2k}} \right)^n
```

by using characters in the latex code so that

```
\alpha shows as α
\sqrt{} shows as √{}
\frac{a}{b} shows as a/b (to spare brackets: a is in superscript and b is in subscript)  
\sum shows as ∑ (there is another sigma for using it as a letter Σ)
\infty shows as ∞
```

Meaning without super-/subscript we would have

```
α(z,n)=\left( √{1/2πi} ∑ k=1 ∞ z^k+n/ x^{2k} \right)^n.
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87257/unicode-in-the-equations-pros-and-cons/87268#87268

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124984/how-does-xetex-typeset-math-symbols-which-are-input-as-unicode/124989#124989

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I use Emacs with preview-latex. It allows in-document preview of such expressions.

Comment: You can use package `unicode-math` with a unicode engine, e.g., using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX. Even unicode sub- and superscripts are possible.

Comment: WinEdt has a package which displays Greek letters and a number of math symbols, while saving the file  as  traditional code.

Comment: You can also [use package `newunicodechar`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96172/9057) for the math characters.